# Calling Sequencial HTTP request 100 times

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Here's the problem statement:

- Two service calls (`/api/postsomedata`) and (`/api/postsomeotherdata`)
- Call both the service calls 100 times sequential(Although no dependency of these two service calls on one another)

I came up with following rxjs implementation using nested `concatMap`:

```
import { range } from 'rxjs/observable/range';
import { concatMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators/tap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-flow',
  templateUrl: './flow.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./flow.component.scss']
})
export class FlowComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public dataCallService: DataCallService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    range(1, 100).pipe(
      tap((d) => console.log(d)),
      concatMap(() => this.dataCallService.firstAPI(data1).pipe(
        concatMap(() => this.dataCallService.secondAPI(data2))
      ))
    ).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res)
    });
  }
 }
```

Although this works fine; `tap` operator I used emits 1 to 100 immediatly. I am not sure whether its correct approach.
Is there any better approach to achieve the same ?

Comment: So do you have to call the two services sequentially or not? Right now you are calling `firstAPI(data1)` and only after it completes you call `secondAPI(data2)` while you're saying there's no dependency between them.

Comment: Even though no dependecy..but backend team wants first API to be called before second API..they are doing some logic at backend..so sequence of calling should be like 

*1-2-1-2-1-2-1-2*... and so on 100 times! (total 200 req :O)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for the requests to be chained, it should be something like:

```
Observable.range(1, 100).map(i =>
  this.dataCallService.firstAPI(data1)
  .concatMap(() => this.dataCallService.secondAPI(data2))
})
.concatAll()
.subscribe(res => {});
```

Request observables can be conveniently handled with promises in Angular, because both `Http` and `HttpClient` result in complete observable with single value.

Unless request observable is supposed to be aborted in the middle of a request or piped with other incomplete/multi-value observables, it may be beneficial to switch to promises.

This results in very straightforward `async` function where `Promise.all` is used for requests that can be performed in parallel:

```
  async ngOnInit() {
    try {
      for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        const [result1, result2] = await Promise.all([
          this.dataCallService.firstAPI(data1).toPromise(),
          this.dataCallService.secondAPI(data2).toPromise()
        ]);
      }
    } catch (err) { ... }
  }
```

Or in series:

```
  async ngOnInit() {
    try {
      for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        const result1 = await this.dataCallService.firstAPI(data1).toPromise();
        const result2 = await this.dataCallService.secondAPI(data2).toPromise();
      }
    } catch (err) { ... }
  }
```

Comment: `Promise.all` is line `forkjoin` isn't it ?..I want sequencial call..dont want to call both services parallel ...one after another

Comment: @Rahul Yes, forkJoin is its RxJS counterpart. The code does what you requested, *Call both the service calls 100 times sequential(Although no dependency of these two service calls on one another)*, so it does 2 requests in parallel. You can avoid Promise.all if you don't need that.

Comment: Ohk..I shall try `async` `await` approach what you have suggested....and shall accept it ! thanks !

So the solution what I used it not a correct approach ? i.e. used `range` and `concatMap` ?

Comment: One doubt...for loop would stop execution of my further code...correct ?

Comment: I added the example with observables for completeness. `for` certainly won't stop anything. `async` is asynchronous.

Comment: although I accepted this as answer ...when I tried again today (Observable approach) it happens that all 100 call for `firstAPI` are happening and then100 calls for `secondAPI` are happening... however I want to get output as ... *1-2-1-2-1-2-1-2...* and so on 100 times (total 200 calls)

Comment: Which snippet did you use? The examples with async/await physically cannot do the thing you're describing.

Comment: Observable.range(1,100)..i used this snippet

Comment: It seems it works ok, http://plnkr.co/edit/SVyJ3rSS2pOETTc7lCVm?p=preview . Any way, I'd stick to promises because they are more expressive than RxJS in such cases.

Comment: thanks...I did someting wrong earlier..working as expected